# Unable to get typescript generated js files to run in IE11

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am trying out Typescript, using visual studio 2017.

I opened a blank directory in Visual studio 2017 ("Add Existing Website"), and added index.html and main.ts.

This is my tsconfig.json file, based on general recommendations:

```
    {
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es3"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include":
    [
        "scripts/**/*"
    ]
}
```

And in index.html i add my file as follows:

```
 <script src="scripts/main.js" ></script>
```

But when i open the page in IE11, i just shows "Syntax error" and the line number. Going to the line number shows **import** and **export** statements

I've tried using requirejs but i get other kinds of errors, and i've tried changing the **module** and **target** in tsconfig.json but nothing seems to have worked.

I don't want dependencies in my code if at all possible, but what do i have to do to get Typescript generated javascript code to execute in IE11?

I have not even attempted to get it to work as far back as IE8.

Or is IE11 no longer considered a browser to be supported ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution...

I had code like this:

```
export module ABC {
    ....
}
```

And in  IE11 this created an error "unknown error exports" as a result of the way JS was generated using the tsconfig settings.

So the solution was to replace **export module ABC** with **namespace ABC** and update my tsconfig.js as follows:

```
{
"compilerOptions":
{
    "target": "es3", //defines what sort of code ts generates, es5 because it's what most browsers currently UNDERSTANDS.
    "module": "none",
    "lib":
    [
        "es2015.promise",
        "es5",
        "dom",
    ]
},
"compileOnSave": true,
"include":
[
    "scripts/*"
]
```

}

Most important was the **"module" : "none"**

Took me ages to figure out, hope it helps someone else.

**UPDATE 1:**

I had to add the "lib" section in compiler options to get the transpiler to not complain about Promise, console and other known keywords.